# How to configure PuTTY to use Windows Kerberos ticket?

Tags: windows, windows-10, putty, active-directory, kerberos

Our network uses Active Directory (duh) and all end-user accounts are in AD (not local). I'm trying to configure PuTTY to use the ticket I obtain automatically, when logging into my Windows workstation, to login into Linux servers as well.

I added the `me@SUBDOMAIN.EXAMPLE.NET` into the `~/.k5login` of the Linux account.

I verified, that it works by:

1. Doing `kinit me@SUBDOMAIN.EXAMPLE.NET` inside a FreeBSD VM running on the Windows workstation.
2. Successfully logging-in via ssh (with both PublicKey and Password authentication methods disabled).

I then configured PuTTY -- the GSSAPI section -- thus:

[image: PuTTY's Connection/SSH/Auth/GSSAPI configuration screen]

and attempted to login to the same Linux server as the same account. To no avail -- I'm still prompted for password.

What am I missing? (I don't have root-access on the Linux system, and am unable to view sshd's logs.)

Invoking `klist` (`C:\Windows\System32\klist.exe`) on a PowerShell prompt lists plenty of tickets.

However, trying to use `plink -v` from command-line (as advised by @user1686), I see the message "No GSSAPI security context available" followed by "GSSAPI authentication initialization failed".

Trying to use the server's FQDN does not change the result, but `plink` no longer shows errors -- still falls back to asking for password, though:

```
...
Trying SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
Trying gssapi-with-mic...
Attempting GSSAPI authentication
GSSAPI authentication initialised
GSSAPI authentication initialised
GSSAPI authentication loop finished OK
me@F.Q.D.N's password:
```

Comment: Are you logged in to an AD account on the Windows client, or a local account? Are you trying to use the ticket Windows acquires automatically for AD users, or are you trying to use MIT Kerberos For Windows? Does the SSH client log (both the "Event Log" in PuTTY and the -v option in `ssh`) show it trying GSSAPI authentication?

Comment: I updated the question. Yes, OpenSSH succeeds with GSSAPI option. I don't know, how to increase verbosity of PuTTY.

Comment: You'll find "Event Log" in the PuTTY window's "system menu" (click the icon in the top-left corner) or the context menu (Ctrl+right click the text/terminal area). Alternatively, `plink.exe -v -noagent my.server.tld` (the CLI version of PuTTY). If PuTTY/plink tries GSSAPI, then does invoking `klist` on a PowerShell prompt list a ticket for `host/your.server.etc` specifically? Also, are you connecting to the server by its "official" AD-joined hostname? Windows doesn't do hostname canonicalization for Kerberos the way krb5 on Linux does.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question once more. (Also, FWIW, FreeBSD uses Heimdal -- not KRB5.)

Comment: Does the log say "Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL"? Does the Windows bundled OpenSSH behave any different? i.e. `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe your.server.etc -v -o GSSAPIAuthentication=yes -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic`. Can you manually get a ticket using `klist.exe get host/your.server.etc`? (Heimdal too does canonicalization using reverse DNS like MIT Krb5, which is relevant when SSH'ing to a host through one of its aliases, whereas Windows at most just expands bare names by appending the domain, and then not always, expecting aliases to be handled by the KDC instead.)

Comment: Yes, `plink` does say "Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL". Microsoft-supplied `ssh.exe` fails with `Corrupted MAC on input.` (?!).  `klist.exe get ...` fails with code 0x6fb...

Comment: Can you check through FreeBSD what was the actual service principal that ssh ended up using (should be cached in the client's `klist`)? Is it for the exact same host name that you're connecting to on Windows? (And whatever principal you found on FreeBSD, can you then `klist.exe get` a ticket for it on Windows?) I think 0x6fb is the error code you'd get when the KDC doesn't have a service with the specified name, while "Corrupted MAC" somehow makes me think you're getting a ticket for one server, but then talking to another. (Is it a cluster/round-robin hostname or something like that?)

Comment: The Linux servers all use a different Kerberos domain here. According to `klist` on FreeBSD, the server's ticket is for `host/F.Q.D.N@ANOTHER.TLD`. But there must be cross-domain trust enabled, because connection from FreeBSD succeeds. No, there is no round-robin, I'm using the actual direct hostname -- not a front-end/alias anything.

But! `klist get` for this long principal succeeds -- and dumps a large list of entries.

Comment: In that case, does `klist.exe get host/F.Q.D.N@ANOTHER.TLD`, with the realm specified, work on Windows? (Do you know if that other Kerberos realm is also AD-based?) Can you get Wireshark installed on Windows and see what requests for which tickets it makes on `port 88`? The way cross-realm tickets are obtained is also different between Windows AD and MIT/Heimdal Kerberos, with Windows relying a bit more on the KDC.

Comment: Yes, `klist.exe get` works for the full name (with the other realm). No, Wireshark is not an option due to restrictions. Linux servers (RedHat) all use `sssd`, which suggests they are AD-controlled, but `/etc/sssd` is inaccessible to mortals, so I cannot confirm it.

Comment: In your last edit, you say that using the FQDN seems to make the GSSAPI process work (so I assume that was the problem that caused Windows not obtain a ticket at all), but if the server is still just rejecting the auth attempt in the end, this now feels like a server-side problem (possibly with the server not accepting cross-realm clients as authorized... even though you did succeed with .k5login earlier).

Comment: Well, connections from inside the FreeBSD VM continue to work. Also, using the Windows version of `ssh.exe` continues to fail -- with the same message about "corrupted MAC".